# No Java-Jose-package supports my ECDHES Curve-algorithm

Tags: encryption, jwe, ecdh, jose

I'm trying set up a JWE encrypted with a given JWK using the ECDH-ES Algorithm and the curve brainpoolP256r1. I would really like to use a Jose package, like Nimbus Jose or jose4j. Unfortunately both don't support the brainpool-curve. I've searched their documentations for days to find out if there is any way to include it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Brainpool curves are not registered for use with JOSE, see https://www.iana.org/assignments/jose/jose.xhtml#web-key-elliptic-curve

Answer (score 0):

As Filip points out, the Brainpool curves are not registered or defined for use with JOSE. But https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/pull-requests/24 might be of interest for DYI with jose4j.